# Find 2 to 4 words with maximum of 2 commas anywhere between them

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

with php's `preg_match()`..

find 2 to 4 words with maximum of 2 commas anywhere between them.

```
$string = "word1,,, word2,,, word3,,, word4, word5, word6,,, word7";
```

the output should be : `word4, word5, word6`

if i change the string to..

```
$string = "word1,,,word2,,,word3,,,word4 word5 word6,,word7 word8";
```

the output should be : `word4 word5 word6,,word7`

because 4 words have been found with only 2 commas between them.

if i modify the regex and change "4" to "5"..
then the output should be : `word4 word5 word6,,word7 word8`

because 5 words have been found with only 2 commas between them.

Comment: show what you have tried, personally I wouldn't use regex, just explode the string and do some counting etc..

Comment: I'd use something like [`(?>\b,{0,2} *\w+){2,4}`](https://regex101.com/r/qXkfAH/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, with some expression similar to,

```
(?:(?<=^|,)[^,\r\n]+,){2,}|(?:(?<=^|,)[^,\r\n]+,{2}){1,}[^,]+
```

you can start.

```
$re = '/(?:(?<=^|,)[^,\r\n]+,){2,}|(?:(?<=^|,)[^,\r\n]+,{2}){1,}[^,]+/';
$str = 'word1,,, word2,,, word3,,, word4, word5, word6,,, word7
word1,,,word2,,,word3,,,word4 word5 word6,,word7 word8';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    $output = trim($value[0], ",");
    print(trim($output) . "\n");
}
```

#### output

```
word4, word5, word6
word4 word5 word6,,word7 word8
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0OewXi/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/0OewXi/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---